# Angular universal / ng-toolkit/universal throws error when image doesn't exist

Tags: angular

I'm using @ng-toolkit/universal for my server-side rendering approach. Everything works fine, without my images. I'm getting them dynamically. So when a user doesn't have an Avatar, there is a placeholder image which gets shown. Therefore I'm using this function:

```
verifyAvatar(imageSrc) {
        let img = new Image;
        img.src = imageSrc;

        if(img.complete){
            this.userAvatar= imageSrc
        } else {
            this.userAvatar= '../../../../assets/images/userGraphics/no_avatar.png';
        }
    }
```

But this function gives ma an error inside my server.ts / logfile ->

> ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.
>   URL Segment:
>   'assets/images/userGraphics/5c38f71e07b6b83f20b46993_avatar'
>   Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'assets/images/userGraphics/5c38f71e07b6b83f20b46993_avatar'

The full error for two images is about 300 - 450 lines long. I hope you understand, that you get confused when your server console is flooded with this.

So how do I deal with Angular universal/Ng-toolkit/universal, so that there is no error thrown?

Just for notification, my function works fine and my server doesn't crash, but I would feel much better when the error is gone.

**Edit:**
I just created a repo to reproduce this -> https://github.com/Sanafan/angularUniversalTest

the error is also thrown when an image is defined:
[image]

Comment: Can you create a small repo on github to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: will take some time... i'll update my answer when repo is finishend, think about an hour maybe.

Comment: finished, maybe you're able to test it out?!

Comment: I'm getting `ERROR ReferenceError: Image is not defined` since there is no Image constructor in nodejs. Try fixing it and you will see that the error `Cannot match any routes` will be thrown away

Comment: nope, that doesn't work. I did not define it because it makes no difference, in my original project it is defined, there is no image error but the cannot match any routes error is thrown anyway.

Comment: Can you try using `/assets/images/userGraphics/userId1Avatar.png` url instead of relative? And the image should exist

Comment: Sorry but did you read the description? The error is thrown although i defined a correct path to a fallback image. Not every user uploads an avatar so therefore you need a fallback like "no avatar uploaded" image which gets set correctly by my function. But although there is a correct loaded image, the error is thrown.

Comment: `../../../../assets/images/userGraphics/no_avatar.png` this is wrong path. Please try `/assets/images/userGraphics/no_avatar.png`

Comment: If server can't find the image then it fallbacks to angular router since all routes are handled by express to index.html and you're getting cannot match any routes

Comment: I added `userId1Avatar.png` to your project and it works without any errors

Comment: My simple reproduction of your issue is having `<img src="/assets/images/userGraphics/undefinedImage.png">` in `app.component.html`

Comment: i changed links inside my project, recompiled it, error is still there... you're meaning sth. different. Of course it works without any errors when `userId1Avatar.png` is there. But there should also be no error, when the user hasn't uploaded an image and the fallback image is shown.

Comment: I wonder how Image class looks like. Seems you need to consider another way to check if an image exists on the server smth like `var fs = require('fs');
if (fs.existsSync(path))`

Comment: Can you share your `Image` implementation?

Comment: Given the error is about routing, what's your route setup?  Maybe you need to exclude the avatar folder?

Comment: the routes are exactly the same. The only difference is the filename. The file of course isn't there, when the user didn't upload an avatar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since angular reply with an error with a md5sum hash, This means there is a setting problem to recognize it as a png file.

What happens, if you replace your component HTML has followed (set `userAvatarSrc` to false when undefined)?

```
<div  *ngIf="userAvatarSrc">
<img [src]="userAvatarSrc"></img>
</div> 
<div  *ngIf="!userAvatarSrc">
<img src="../../assets/images/userGraphics/noAvatar.png"></img>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Angular Universal much, but, as far as I have read/known, you are setting `dist/browser` folder as a static resource in express server.

Now, in your `verifyAvatar` function, you are creating an HTMLImageElement (`new Image`), and assigning `src` in the very next line.

So, the server will try to create an Image element, with provided src value. In your case, it won't find any image at a given path (src) and will log errors.

After above, it will continue to check the angular condition (`if (img.complete)`), which will be `false` and the correct path will be assigned to `userAvatar` variable. And you would see correct image in the browser.

So, the errors which you are seeing in a terminal window (at server-side), are coming because you are trying to create Image element with the path, which does not have any image.

To avoid this, you must check image existence at server-side only.